# Trace(ABBA) for $2 \times 2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I want to show the following formula for $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in a field $K$.

$$\operatorname{tr}(ABBA) = 2 \det(A)\det(B) + \operatorname{tr}(A)\operatorname{tr}(B)\operatorname{tr}(AB) - \det(A) (\operatorname{tr} B)^2 - \det(B)(\operatorname{tr} A)^2,$$

where $2=1+1$. After some manipulations I arrived at

$$\operatorname{tr}(ABBA) = [\ldots] - \operatorname{tr}(ABBA),$$

but then I need to assume $1+1 \neq 0$ in $K$ to obtain the formula.

Is there a proof which holds in the general case but doesn't use brute force computation?

Comment: The explicit computation always works, in any characteristic. It is not so complicated, so I don't see a problem. If $A$ has entries $a_i$, and  $B$ has entries $b_j$, then both sides are equal to $$a_1^2b_1^2 + a_1^2b_2b_3 + a_1a_2b_1b_3 + a_1a_2b_3b_4 + a_1a_3b_1b_2 + a_1a_3b_2b_4 + a_2a_3
b_1^2 + 2a_2a_3b_2b_3 + a_2a_3b_4^2 + a_2a_4b_1b_3 + a_2a_4b_3b_4 + a_3a_4b_1b_2 + a_3a_4b_2b_4 +
a_4^2b_2b_3 + a_4^2b_4^2$$

Comment: You are right. I was curious as to why characteristic 2 causes these problems, but of course we can also say that the explicit computation is the standard way and if something else works in characteristic not equal 2, then we are just lucky.

Comment: I guess that the above identity follows from some other identity, which has an easier proof, using, say, Cayley-Hamilton. However, this is not obvious, if you start from this identity.

Comment: This follows immediately from Cayley-Hamilton theorem if you rewrite $\operatorname{tr}(ABBA)$ as $\operatorname{tr}(AABB)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cayley-Hamilton we have

$$A^2 - (\operatorname{tr} A) A + (\det A) I = 0,$$

so

$$A^2B^2 - (\operatorname{tr} A) AB^2 + (\det A) B^2 = 0.$$

Now apply the trace to obtain

$$\operatorname{tr}(A^2B^2) - (\operatorname{tr} A)(\operatorname{tr} AB^2) + (\det A)(\operatorname{tr} B^2) = 0.$$

Again by Cayley-Hamilton we have

$$B^2 - (\operatorname{tr} B) B + (\det B) I = 0,$$

so

$$\operatorname{tr} B^2 = (\operatorname{tr} B)^2 - 2\det B.$$

Also,

$$AB^2 - (\operatorname{tr} B) AB + (\det B) A = 0.$$

Thus

$$\operatorname{tr} AB^2 = (\operatorname{tr} B)(\operatorname{tr} AB) - (\det B)(\operatorname{tr} A).$$

Finally, collecting everything yields the desired identity.

The comments helped me to find this solution. Thanks a lot!